# Sum of resulting set of rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CU.permit_id, CU.month, /*CU.year,*/ M.material_id, M.material_name, /*MC.chemical_id, C.chemical_name,
C.precursor_organic_compound, C.non_precursor_organic_compound,*/
/*MC.chemical_percentage,*/
POC_emissions =
        CASE
        WHEN (C.precursor_organic_compound = 'true')
                THEN (CU.chemical_usage_lbs / CU.material_density) * M.VOC
        ELSE 0
        END,
NON_POC_emissions = 
        CASE
        WHEN (C.non_precursor_organic_compound = 'true')
                THEN CU.chemical_usage_lbs * (MC.chemical_percentage / 100)
        ELSE 0
        END
FROM material M
LEFT OUTER JOIN material_chemical MC ON MC.material_id = M.material_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN chemical_usage CU ON CU.material_id = MC.material_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN chemical C ON C.chemical_id = MC.chemical_id
WHERE (CU.month >=1 AND CU.month <= 2)
AND CU.year = 2013
AND M.material_id = 52
--AND CU.permit_id = 2118
--GROUP BY CU.permit_id, M.material_id, M.material_name, CU.month, MC.chemical_id, MC.chemical_id, C.chemical_name, C.precursor_organic_compound, C.non_precursor_organic_compound
--ORDER BY C.chemical_name ASC
```

Which returns:

[image]

But what I need is to return one row per month per material adding up the values of POC per month and NON_POC per month.

So, I should end up with something like:

```
Month    material_id     material_name     POC           NON_POC
1        52              Krylon...         0.107581      0.074108687
2        52              Krylon...         0.143437      0.0988125
```

I tried using SUM but it sums up the same result multiple times:

```
SELECT /*DISTINCT*/ CU.permit_id, CU.month, /*CU.year,*/ M.material_id, M.material_name, /*MC.chemical_id, C.chemical_name,
C.precursor_organic_compound, C.non_precursor_organic_compound,*/
--MC.chemical_percentage,
POC_emissions = SUM( 
        CASE
        WHEN (C.precursor_organic_compound = 'true')
                THEN (CU.chemical_usage_lbs / CU.material_density) * M.VOC
        ELSE 0
        END),
NON_POC_emissions = SUM( 
        CASE
        WHEN (C.non_precursor_organic_compound = 'true')
                THEN CU.chemical_usage_lbs * (MC.chemical_percentage / 100)
        ELSE 0
        END)
FROM material M
LEFT OUTER JOIN material_chemical MC ON MC.material_id = M.material_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN chemical_usage CU ON CU.material_id = MC.material_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN chemical C ON C.chemical_id = MC.chemical_id
WHERE M.material_id = 52
--AND CU.permit_id = 187
AND (CU.month >=1 AND CU.month <= 2)
AND CU.year = 2013
GROUP BY CU.permit_id, M.material_id, M.material_name, CU.month/*, CU.year, MC.chemical_id, C.chemical_name, C.precursor_organic_compound, C.non_precursor_organic_compound*/
--ORDER BY C.chemical_name ASC
```

[image]

Comment: In the first query you have `DISTINCT` keyword. Can you output data without `DISTINCT` keyword?

Comment: SQL server or MySQL? which one is it?

Comment: @Barranka is SQL Server, sorry.

Comment: It's not clear what's wrong with your actual output. `NON_POC_emissions` seems to be very close to your desired result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first query has a `DISTINCT` clause. What is the output without the `DISTINCT` clause. I suspect you have more rows than shows in your screenshot.

Regardless, you could try something like this to get the desired result.

```
select permit_id, month, material_id, material_name, 
       sum(poc_emissions), sum(non_poc_emissions)
from (

    SELECT DISTINCT CU.permit_id, CU.month, M.material_id, M.material_name, 
    POC_emissions =
        CASE
        WHEN (C.precursor_organic_compound = 'true')
                THEN (CU.chemical_usage_lbs / CU.material_density) * M.VOC
        ELSE 0
        END,
    NON_POC_emissions = 
        CASE
        WHEN (C.non_precursor_organic_compound = 'true')
                THEN CU.chemical_usage_lbs * (MC.chemical_percentage / 100)
        ELSE 0
        END
    FROM material M
    LEFT OUTER JOIN material_chemical MC ON MC.material_id = M.material_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN chemical_usage CU ON CU.material_id = MC.material_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN chemical C ON C.chemical_id = MC.chemical_id
    WHERE (CU.month >=1 AND CU.month <= 2)
      AND CU.year = 2013
      AND M.material_id = 52

) main
group by permit_id, month, material_id, material_name
```

**Explanation**

Since the results you retrieved by doing a `DISTINCT` was consider source-of-truth, I created an in-memory table by making it a sub-query. However, this subquery must have a name of some kind...whatever name. I gave it a name `main`. Subqueries look like this:

```
select ... from (sub-query) <give-it-a-table-name>

Simple Example:
select * from (select userid, username from user) user_temp

Advanced Example:
select * from (select userid, username from user) user_temp
inner join (select userid, sum(debits) as totaldebits from debittable) debit
    on debit.userid = user_temp.userid
```

Notice how `user_temp` alias for the subquery can be used as if the sub-query was a real table.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. Could you explain it a little bit please? What is that 'main' for? Thanks

Comment: Absolutely. I have added an explanation. Let me know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 2):

Use above query in subquery and group by (month) and select sum(POC_emissions) and sum(NON_POC_emissions )